# how is xml stored in database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with one of the column being of type xml
 I enetered record as insert into table_1 values(1,'')
i opened the mdf file in hex i found the "<>" missing.
This is how it looks.

```
00000000:   30000800 01000000 02000001 002b00df †0............+..         
00000010:   ff01b004 f0077000 72006f00 64007500 †......p.r.o.d.u.         
00000020:   63007400 ef000001 f801f7            †††††††††††††c.t........
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care what the bytes look like in a hex editor?  Are you running XML queries from the output of your hex editor?

Answer (score 2):

mdf = SQL Server.

Which version? What is the field like?

XML field - well...
...it is stored in form of data (not documented), not as text. This is mosstly done to support the advanced query functionality. Not ethat this means storing XML and retrieving it may CHANGE THE STRING - as surplus spaces are removed. This eliminates... the validity of signed XML elements (if you use signatures in XML).

Basically, the XML structure is parsed and the data stored in a separate database structure.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
i'm using SQL Server 2005.
I had inserted an xml as <product/> in my database.(The hex dump of the record is mentioned above)
the tag <product/> is stored as
4ACDC06F:   dfff01b0 04f00770 0072006f 00640075 †.......p.r.o.d.u         

4ACDC07F:   00630074 00ef0000 01f801f7 ††††††††††.c.t........

Can you help me reconstruct the tag ?
Thanks

Comment: Nope, sorry. Why the heck (sorry) do you need that to start with? ;) I mean, I do SQL Server heavily for about 10 years now, and never had to deal with db storage internals.